# Search with grep only lines that start with #

Tags: regex, unix, terminal, grep

before i get my ass kicked, I want you to know that I checked several documents on "grep" and I couldn't find what I'm looking for or maybe my English is too limited to get the idea.

I have a lot of markdown documents. Each document contain a first level heading (#) which is always on line 1.

I can search for `^#` and that works, but how can I tell grep to look for certain words on the line that starts with `#`?

I want this this

```
grep 'some words' file.markdown
```

But also specify that the line starts with a `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep '^# \([^ ].*\)\{0,1\}some words' file.markdown
```

Or, using ERE syntax

```
grep -E '^# ([^ ].*)?some words' file.markdown
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `#` - a `#` char
- `\([^ ].*\)\{0,1\}` - an optional sequence of patterns (a `\(...\)` is a capturing group in BRE syntax, in ERE, it is `(...)`) (`\{0,1\}` is an interval quantifier that repeats the pattern it modifies 1 or 0 times):

  - `[^ ]` - any char but a space
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `some words` - `some words` text.

See an [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/cWT494):

```
s="# Get me some words here
#some words here I don't want
# some words here I need"
grep '^# \([^ ].*\)\{0,1\}some words' <<< "$s"
# => # Get me some words here
#    # some words here I need
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for. The dot matches any charachter, right? Is it possible to be more specific telling grep that's a white space after #

Comment: #\s.* will do that.

Comment: @ZoltanKing Sure, just add a space: `grep '^# .*some words' file.markdown`. Or, to match any whitespace, `grep '^#[[:space:]].*some words' file.markdown`. Instead of `[[:space:]]` you may also use `[[:blank:]]` (here, they will behave the same).

Comment: Thank you! It works however I would like to match only if it's one space after # and not more

Comment: @ZoltanKing That is not a problem, see updated answer.